# Can org-provide-todo-statistics be set locally for a specific tree?

Tags: org-mode, customize

Sometimes I would like a tree's statistics cookie, for example "[1/3]", to be calculated differently than what is specified in the global value for `org-provide-todo-statistics`.

For example, I might find it more useful to use `ALL-HEADLINES`, which will include non-TODO items in its count. Or I might like the cookie to be based on a different set of TODO keywords from the global value.

Is it possible to customize `org-provide-todo-statistics` at the tree or subtree level? Perhaps via a property or some other setting?

Comment: Not that I know of, but you can set it as a local file variable: the local value would apply to the whole file. See [file variables](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/File-Variables.html)

Comment: @NickD I have been able to change the value of `org-provide-todo-statistics` using a file variable, as you suggested. I haven't been able to get it working the way I hoped though. I will fiddle with it some more and get back to you. The current issue may be due to something outside of the scope of this question.